# Plotly color factor data stopped working - error package scale

Tags: r, plot, colors, version, plotly

I got an error in a plotly plot when using colors for factor data.

Example that gives an error for me:

```
library(plotly)
test <- data.frame(x=1:10, y = exp(1:10), z = rep(c('A', 'B'), each=5))
plot_ly(test, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~z)
```

I got this error:

```
Error in .Call("_scales_doColorRamp", PACKAGE = "scales", colors, x, alpha,  : 
  "_scales_doColorRamp" not available for .Call() for package "scales"
```

This suggest that it is an error due to an update in package scales.

Are there more that are facing this problem?
I am using R version 3.4.1, plotly version 4.7.1 and scales version 0.5.0.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. Your code does not throw errors on my R.

Comment: @Marco, are you using the same package versions? 
The error occurred after I updated R and packages.

Comment: you are sure you are using the same versions for plotly and scales?

Comment: Dont ask me why, but it worked when I again reinstalled the package scales again. Its still using the same version but I think something is changed withing the package somewhere in my workflow.
Anyway, thanks for your help Marco

Comment: same issue with `heatmapply`, after updading to R 3.4.2. Also solved after reinstalling `scales`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing and reinstalling the package `scales` did solve this issue